# Stylist Css Border Creation

Tags: css, border

Is it possible to create a border like the flowing image with css? Any hints will be appreciated

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGwQ6.png]

[image]

```
#sidebar h4, #sidebar-alt h4 {
    background:url('images/widget-title-bg.png'); 
    color: #333333;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal; 
    margin: 0 0 10px 0; 
    padding: 7px 0px 11px 0px; 
    }
```

Comment: you want to make a static image like this or this image will override with blue color?

Comment: how do you want to use vertical   or horizontal ? you can do this by background-image ... but id doesnot support it

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/roine/WhzNf/

Comment: @JonathandeM. I think he wanna make a progress bar so, if you use that blue color as border then he will also have decrease width of div with the increase of border width, well your fiddle is appreciated!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/shameed/KXA3V/

Comment: @tnx guys 4 ur effort -I was actually trying to create a border under widget title like this image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/k97Jh.png with css. Since I’m newbie to css, while doing I was massing it up every time. Ya i know that it can easily be done by the flowing way 

`
#sidebar h4, #sidebar-alt h4 { 
 background:url('images/widget-title.png');  
 color: #333; 
 font-size: 22px; 
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif; 
 font-weight: normal;  
 margin: 0 0 10px 0;  
 padding: 7px 0px 11px 0px;  
}

`
But I think it would be good if it can be done by css which will reduce an unnecessary http call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this link Visit 
        (http://jsfiddle.net/qD4zd/1/).
 See if it helps. This tells you about the application of gradient. See how it is done.
Also why not use directly the images that you want as the border.
Check out for "Gradient" in Css. This might answer your question.

Comment: @ArafinShaon:Posting "up-vote" is equivalent to thanks.:) Always stick to the "up-vote" than the thanks comment.:)

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Made some changes according to your comments. Try:

```
<h1 id="progress">
    <i></i>Recent Posts
</h1>​
#progress {
    display: block;
    max-width: 200px;
    min-width: 150px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px auto 0;
    padding: 0 3px;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #ECECEC;
    font: bold 26px 'Dancing Script', cursive;
}
#progress i {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: .8em;
    height: 10px;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -10px;
    background-color: #4287F4;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/z45QJ/4/

I'm not a big fan of the `position` manipulation, but all browsers should support and display this nearly identically, the only possible problem being the font's displa may be slightly differently in different browsers. However, IE7-9 should interpret everything else just fine.

---

Too bad the whole wuuurld isn't on WebKit:

```
<div id="progress"></div>​

#progress {
    width: 300px;
    height: 10px;
    border: none;
    background-color: #ECECEC;
    border-left: solid #4287F4;
    box-shadow:inset 2px 0 white;
    -webkit-animation: slide 10s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slide {
    from {
        border-left-width: 0;
        width: 300px;
    } to {
        border-left-width: 300px;
        width: 0;
    }
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/z45QJ/1

It could be adjusted to go both ways. However, it only works on WebKit browsers (Chrome, Safari [?]). If that's ok, let me know and I'll add the return trip.

Answer (score 1):

There are four ways to do it. [I demonstrate four ways in this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YyQk9/), and here are some explanations.

If you're not sure, just use Method B.

## Method A

Method A has the advantage that it's the most compatible but the disadvantage that it requires extra HTML. Basically, you're giving an outer div the blue border and an inner div the white border. Your HTML will look something like this:

```
<div class="methodA">
    <div class="container">
        Method A
    </div>
</div>
```

Your CSS will look like this:

```
.methodA {
    border-left: 10px solid blue;
}
.methodA .container {
    height: 100%;
    border-left: 10px solid white;
}
```

## Method B

Method B has the advantage that there's no extra HTML, but the disadvantage is that [it won't work in IE before version 9](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow).

```
.methodB {
    border-left: 10px solid blue;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 10px 0 white;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 10px 0 white;
    box-shadow: inset 10px 0 white;
}
```

You can mitigate IE's compatibility issues using [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/documentation/getting-started/), which makes box shadows behave in Internet Explorer (along with other CSS3 features).

## Methods C and D

[This JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YyQk9/) shows two other methods, which I won't describe in as much detail, but...

- Method C makes the blue border a shadow. As a result, it can "cover" other elements and it also changes the size of the element. I don't love this solution, but it might work for you. It also suffers the compatibility issues of Method B.
- Method D puts two divs inside of the element: one for the blue border and one for the right border.

Answer (score 1):

it is not really complicate and no extra HTML is needed.

```
h4:after {
    display:block;
    content: '';
    height:4px;
    width: 1px;
    border:0px solid #ececec;
    border-left-width: 10px;
    border-left-color:#4287F4;
    border-right-width: 90px;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/N27CH/

Answer (score 0):

I studied some usage of "canvas" tag in HTML5. That is preety much informative about gradient specification and is also more readable than the traditionl HTML4. So for this question i also want to request the questioner to look at the "canvas" tag in HTML5. check the link below.

```
    Link: http://html5center.sourceforge.net/Using-Unprefixed-CSS3-Gradients-in-Modern-Browsers

    Link: http://www.sendesignz.com/index.php/web-development/111-how-to-create-gradient-and-shadow-effect-in-html5-canvas
```

Second link is more awesome. Cheers.:)